# htaccess, request uri wont redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want a redirection to "index_de.html" if the request uri is "de", else everybody should be redirected to index.html. Why is my code not working?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/de
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index_de.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^de/.*$ /index_de.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

Keep more specific rules before generic catch-all types.